# scala: define a Type that has defined a certain implicit

Tags: scala, types, playframework-2.0

I want to define a function with a generic type T, in which for T there's an implicit implementation of a certain method

In fact I'm trying to achieve the following:

I have very repetitive code like this:

```
def update(id: Long) = CORSAction { implicit request =>
  request.body.asJson.map { json =>
    json.asOpt[Wine].map { wine =>
      wine.copy(id=Id(id)).update.fold(
        errors => JsonBadRequest(errors),
        wine => Ok(toJson(wine).toString)
      )
    }.getOrElse       (JsonBadRequest("Invalid Wine entity"))
  }.getOrElse         (JsonBadRequest("Expecting JSON data"))
}
```

So, checking if it's a valid json and then parsing it, is a very common task that I'd like to encapsulate in a function.

For the wine type I have defined an implicit JsonWineFormatter which implements a writes and reads method to parse from json and render as json a wine object

```
object WineFormatter {

  implicit object JsonWineFormatter extends Format[Wine] {

    def writes(o: Wine): JsValue = {
      toJson( Map(
        "id"          -> toJson(o.id),
    [...]

    def reads(j: JsValue): Wine = {
      Wine(
        id = (j \ "id").as[Option[Pk[Long]]] 
    [...]
```

So I'm trying to define a generic method like this:

```
def parse[T](implicit request: Request[AnyContent]): Option[T] = {
  request.body.asJson.map { json =>
    json.asOpt[T].map { entity =>
      entity
    }
  }
}
```

But I get the followgin error:

**No Json deserializer found for type T. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.**

I need to specify that the generic type T needs and implicit Reads...

Do you know how to achieve it?

--

edit: I tried with the following:

```
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
type EntityWithJsonFormatter[T] = T {def reads(j: JsValue): T}

def parse[T: EntityWithJsonFormatter](request: Request[AnyContent]): Option[T] = {
  request.body.asJson.map { json =>
    json.asOpt[T].map { entity =>
      entity
    }
  }
}
```

But obviously, it's not T the one supossed to implement reads, instead there should be an implicit object that implements it. I don't know how to specify that in a type...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JsValue` docs define `asOpt` thus:

```
def asOpt [T] (implicit fjs: Reads[T]): Option[T]
```

So if you `import play.api.libs.json.Reads` then

```
def parse[T: Reads]( ...
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Regardless of whether a format for opts is implemented, I'm still curious how you'd go about defining a generic function and passing T into Json.fromJson[T] and not getting the 'No Json deserializer found for type T' error.